# Change Magento 1.9 domain name - nothing will solve

Tags: magento-1.9

I need to change a magento domain to a temporary IP this way for development:

http://www.domain.com > http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx/domain

I made several searches, changes to core_config_data and everytime I try the new URL it sends me back to http://www.domain.com. The problem also occurs on /admin.

Anyone has the answer for that ?

THank you !

Gustavo

Comment: change it from the admin panel instead- *Base URL* and *BaseURL Secure*

Comment: I cannot reach admin panel cause it redirects to the production site with production database.

Comment: Still nothing, anyone can help me ?

Comment: have you tried Rewrite base using your htaccess? I think that's the only way you can do that in regard to the case you have. I post an answer with an example

Answer (score 0):

try it through **`.htaccess`** using RewriteBase
check this example here

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteBase /~username/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^xxx\.xxx\.xxx\.xxx [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Unfortunately it made no changes. It keeps redirecting. It must be something in the database.

Comment: try cache:flush then check agai. It should work